# How to Assign Category to a Post Automatically using Postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, post-meta

I've read other answers about assigning category based on post tags. But can this be done based on postmeta?

I'm assuming it can be and I've been trying to change the following snippet (quoted in another answer) to achieve this. But I've had no luck tweaking it to reference postmeta meta_key (delivery_option) and meta_value (pick-up, postal, post & parcel), to then auto assign a category (pick-up, postal or post & parcel).

In case it's relevant, the above postmeta key and value have been added by another plugin.

```
function auto_add_category ($product_id = 0) {
if (!$product_id) return;

// because we use save_post action, let's check post type here
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
if ( "product" != $post_type ) return;

$tag_categories = array (
    'ring' => 'Jewellery'
    'necklace' => 'Jewellery',
    'dress' => 'Clothing',
);

// get_terms returns ALL terms, so we have to add object_ids param to get terms to a specific product
$product_tags = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'object_ids' => $product_id ) );
foreach ($product_tags as $term) {
    if ($tag_categories[$term->slug] ) {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'name', $tag_categories[$term->slug], 'product_cat' );
        $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
        if ($cat_id) {
            $result =  wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $cat_id, 'product_cat', true );
        }
    }
}
}
add_action('save_post','auto_add_category');
```

Disclosure: I'm building a WordPress website and learning as I go. This may be an obvious question, but be assured that its being asked after hours of research to try and answer myself (it's all good I've learnt other stuff while researching... just not the right stuff!). HUGE thanks in advance for any mastery insights.

Comment: Just use the get_post_meta function to get the value of delivery_option then set the category based on that.

Comment: Cheers for the insight Andrew. That sounds less complicated than the above snippet. Will work on writing that up (baby steps!) and post an update.

Comment: Tried this... was kind of hopeful it would work!
function add_category ($product_id=0){
$cat_id = get_post_meta ($post_id, $key='delivery_option') ;}
add_action('save_post','add_category');

Didn't work. Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: I've added my solution for you that will auto add a category when you save the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code when placed in your **functions.php** file will check the product's delivery option and then assign the corresponding category to the product.  If any product categories for that product already exist it will append them to the list.  The product category would need to exist in the first place and if it does then it assigns that category with the same slug as the delivery option.  I use the hook **save_post_product** so that it fires only on updating products.

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'update_product_category', 20, 3);

function update_product_category( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $delivery_methods = array( 'pick-up', 'postal', 'post', 'parcel' );

    $delivery_option = get_post_meta($post_id, 'delivery_option', true);

    if( ! empty( $delivery_option ) ) {
        $product_cats = $product->get_category_ids();

        foreach( $delivery_methods as $delivery_method) {
            if( $delivery_option === $delivery_method ) {
                $pickup_cat_id = get_term_by('slug', $delivery_method, 'product_cat')->term_id;

                if( $pickup_cat_id && ! in_array( $pickup_cat_id, $product_cats) ) {
                    $product_cats[] = $pickup_cat_id;
                    $product->set_category_ids($product_cats);
                    $product->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works a treat when updating in the backend! I'll be honest I didn't get anywhere near your code... really appreciate it. One thing is that it doesn't work when updating or adding a new product from the front end (using Woocommerce Frontend Manager plugin). Is there a better hook you would suggest for this?

Comment: @BeckPerth I'm not familiar with that plugin, it probably has some custom hooks that you can use.  If you open another new question and tag me in it I'll get my hands on the plugin and help you out.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Andrew. Not sure I'm able to tag yet.. so just added question "How to auto-update product category from frontend when using Woocommerce Frontend Manager plugin"